Group of teenage girls at a boarding school have this club to try to help other girls from commiting suicide
I'm racking my brain. This new girl comes tothis boarding school and is accepted by a group of about 4 or 5 other girls who have this club type thing to help girls at their school from committing suicide. They used to go up in the attack of their school at night and eat food out of cans and talk? Then after one of the girl's (the main girl. Well dressed. Closed off. Blonde) boyfriend dumps her, she finds herself wanting to die, so she leaves the school for a while, stays in a hotel, and one day, she discovers this hotel soap that she said gave her hope. And she comes back to the school. 

Fav'd because I want to learn about the "hotel soap that gave her hope" (?). How do I have to imagine this?

@his This film is just weird like that. Think Clueless as directed by Wes Anderson.

Sounds like Damsels in Distress from 2011 with Greta Gerwig and Adam Brody. From Wiki:

Newly transferred college student Lily becomes friends with Violet, Heather and Rose, a clique who run the campus' suicide prevention centre. 

And quoth Violet about a bar of soap she finds in a hotel bathroom: "This scent and this soap is what gives me hope." Here's the trailer:



